# Шифратор. HashMap

Tags: java

Ребят, у меня такой вопрос: я хочу создать шифратор морзянки с помощью HashMap. Я ввел весь латинский алфавит, сделал функцию ввода текста, но не знаю как сделать так, чтобы программа читала введенный юзером текст и переводила ее на морзе. Предполагаю, что нужно использовать оператор if, но не знаю каким образом.
P.S Я новичок.
Вот код:

```
package teach;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Teach {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        String User=in.nextLine();
        Map<String, String> hm = new HashMap<String, String>();    
        hm.put("a", ".-");
        hm.put("b", "-...");
        hm.put("c", "-.-.");
        hm.put("d", "-..");
        hm.put("e",".");
        hm.put("f","..-.");
        hm.put("g","--.");
        hm.put("h","....");
        hm.put("i","..");
        hm.put("j",".---");
        hm.put("k","-.-");
        hm.put("l",".-..");
        hm.put("m","--");
        hm.put("n","-.");
        hm.put("o","---");
        hm.put("p",".--.");
        hm.put("q","--.-");
        hm.put("r",".-.");
        hm.put("s","...");
        hm.put("t","-");
        hm.put("u","..-");
        hm.put("v","...-");
        hm.put("w",".--");
        hm.put("x","-..-");
        hm.put("y","-.--");
        hm.put("z","--..");
        for (String key : hm.keySet()) {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пробегаем в цикле по введенному слову, и далее во внутреннем цикле пробегаем по буквам, если совпадают - выводим.

```
for (char letter : User.toCharArray()) {
    for (String key : hm.keySet()) {
        if (letter == key.charAt(0)) {
            System.out.print(hm.get(key));
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
    }
}
```

https://ideone.com/KJECCQ

Вообще, я бы рекомендовал бы сделать как минимум `Map<Character, String>`, а не `Map<String, String>`, чтобы не приходилось делать в цикле `key.charAt(0)` (по факту конечно не только для этого :)) ), а просто сравнивать буквы.... Потому, что у вас же ключ - символ, а не строка. Тогда нужно сразу так и объявить.

Пример с чарами:

```
for (char letter : User.toCharArray()) {
    for (char key : hm.keySet()) {
        if (letter == key) {
            System.out.print(hm.get(key));
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
    }
}
```

https://ideone.com/gah6S9

Comment: Спасибо за совет: Map<char, String>, но это не работает. Просто подчеркивается красным.

Comment: Потому, что надо не примитивный тип вписывать.. Т.е. `Character` .... то есть `Map<Character, String>` .... и данные будут `hm.put('a', ".-");
        hm.put('b', "-...");` и так далее... то есть уже одинарные кавычки

Comment: Спасибо! Для заполнения символов.

Comment: Пример для чаров привел в ответе тоже